# CommonJS require function not found running iOS Adhoc/Enterprise

Tags: appcelerator, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-alloy

I have an Appcelerator Alloy 6.3.0 iOS app that runs fine on device when running in development.

I packaged the app using my enterprise certificate then build my .ipa and install (and trust) the app on the device.

The app runs fine but then throws an error when attempting to use the commonJS library (pure JS).

```
try{
    var netUtil = require('API');
    netUtil.getList($.labelModel.text, myCallBackFunction);
catch(e){
    alert('Error: ' + e);
}
```

The error shown is...

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'a.getList(k.label-Model.text,g)' )
```

The exact same code runs fine on device without changes when running dev certificate with/without liveview.

**What may be causing CommonJS require function not found only when running iOS .ipa Adhoc/Enterprise ?**

Comment: Can you try by renaming the require file to something non-generic name as **API** name may be reserved for some internal Apple APIs? Rename it like **custom_titanium_file.js** & then try again.

Comment: OMG - that actually fixed the problem!

Comment: Yeah, sometimes solutions are simple as opposite to what they seem. Posting it as an answer & you can mark it as accepted to let others know it has been solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that **`API`** name is reserved in Apple's internal apis or could be used by Titanium itself. So you should rename your **`API.js`** file to something non-generic like **`custom_api.js` or `my_api.js`** & then try again.

I have had this issue once when I named some lib file to **`animation.js`** or something like this (not remember exactly) & figured out that it's always better & safer to use underscore formatting while naming lib files or other js files because internal apis mostly don't use underscore name formatting.